# Unable to insert ajax returned data into input field

Tags: jquery, ajax

The Ajax Request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/CI2/index.php/login/testfunc",
    data: {macro: selectedmacro},
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#tinyeditor').val(data);
        $('#p2').html(data);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
echo "This is a test";
```

HTML

```
<p id = 'p2'>fer</p>
<input type = "text" id = "tinyeditor" />
```

**What Works:**

`$('#p2').html(data);` works and replaces "fer" with "This is a test"

`$('#tinyeditor').val('data');` also works and inserts "data" string into the input field

**The Problem**

`$('#tinyeditor').val(data);` fails to insert "This is a test" into the input field. The field remains blank.

Comment: did you try `$('#tinyeditor').val(data.toString()); `?

Comment: have you tried `alert(data)` to see what exactly you are getting in it? it may contains some tags.

Comment: Mohit - .toString() did not make any difference  and Bhushan alert(data) showed "This is a test". Thats all.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(data)` to insert into `val()`. If you do not specify `dataType` param to ajax, it catches the Mime type of the data.

Comment: Thanks Shaunak and Prasanna. Parsing it did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse the data using `JSON.parse(data)` and try to insert.